# How to protect files - accessing from unauthorized user in Yaws server

Tags: erlang, yaws

I have thousands of files are saved in Yaws media server but files can be accessed by typing URL "like www.domainname.com/images/1.jpg", I want to block user to accessing files from URL - only authorized users can access files.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `auth` block to your server configuration and use a `.yaws_auth` file to allow only authenticated access to your media directory. For example, if your `images` dir is directly under your server docroot, add an `auth` block like this to your server configuration:

```
<auth>
    dir = images
    realm = yourrealm
</auth>
```

You can then add a `.yaws_auth` file to the `images` directory, where each line of the file contains username and password in the form of an Erlang tuple:

```
{Username, Password}.
```

Don't forget to end each line with a '.' character.

See the [Yaws configuration documentation](http://yaws.hyber.org/yman.yaws?page=yaws.conf) for more details.

Comment: thank you for help. I have the same issue i follow your answer but when i copy-paste URL in browser address bar and press Enter key image visible but when press F5 or refresh page page request username and passwod.

Comment: @ Steve Vinoski I have more than 50000 users  so i am  maintaining  user Credentials in db .So how to protect url ? what is best way to doing it ? Here is my question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618177/how-to-prevent-user-to-direct-access-of-url-from-unauthorised-user-in-yaws-webse?noredirect=1#comment60844053_36618177

Comment: @SunilSingh: for the first issue, you're likely hitting a cache. Refreshing the page forces the request to actually go to Yaws, which is working correctly. For the second issue, if you have a database of users, then you need a login system -- see chapter 7 of [the Yaws documentation](http://yaws.hyber.org/yaws.pdf).